# NuGet servers on different networks

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package-restore, nuget-server

I have a project that has dependency to some nuget package.
This nuget package exists on both `nuget1` and `nuget2` servers.
The issue is that the servers are located on different networks. I have only one available at the same time. When restoring tries to connect to unavailable `nuget1` server it says 404 and fails. It doesn't try to restore from `nuget2`. How can I solve the issue? Can I ask nuget to use `nuget2` in case `nuget1` is unavailable?

Comment: Do machines switch between the two networks?

Comment: No, the project should be buildable from different machine. That is why I cannot set correct server's order in the nuget.config. Some machines have acces to `nuget1` but others to `nuget2`.

Comment: Then you could make a DNS setting for each network that points to the correct Nuget server

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to use some project-specific setting instead of OS-specific if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All configured NuGet package sources must be available for package installation and restore to work.

From [GitHub: package resolution fails if unreachable source exists](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2598):

> For example imagine the server is intermittently off, and it has a new version of xunit. As a user you will get quietly an inconsistent experience between multiple installs.
>
> This seems simple enough when you install a single package with no dependencies, but get quickly out of hand when you have a reasonably large package graph, that would lead you to losing days.

So one option could be to use the same DNS name for both servers, and let the network admin register that name on each network pointing to the appropriate server.

So on network 1, a DNS alias `nugetserver` exists and points to `10.0.0.1`, and on network 2 a DNS alias `nugetserver` points to `192.168.1.1`.

Then in Visual Studio, you configure one server, namely `nugetserver`, as a package source.